# Improving port scanner performance

Tags: c++, windows, winsock2

So I made a port scanner in C++ this morning and it seems to work alright, just having one rather annoying issue with it- whenever I use it to scan an IP over the network, it takes a good 10-20 seconds PER port.

It seems like the connect() method is what's taking it so long.

Now aside from multi-threading, which I'm sure will speed up the process but not by much, how could I make this faster? Here is the section of code that does the scanning:

```
for (i = 0; i < a_size(port_no); i++)
{
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    target.sin_family = AF_INET;
    target.sin_port = htons(port_no[i]);
    target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);

    if (connect(sock, (SOCKADDR *)&target, sizeof(target)) != SOCKET_ERROR)
        cout << "Port: " << port_no[i] << " - open" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Port: " << port_no[i] << " - closed" << endl;
    closesocket(sock);
}
```

If you need more let me know.

Oh also, I am using the winsock2.h file. Is it because of this that its so slow?

Comment: There may be some sort of timeout that you're missing.

Comment: If you want to reduce the amount of time waiting to connect make it a non-blocking socket and call `select` after `connect`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, i actually think i read that online somewhere too. I will give it a shot later today when i get the chance. Thanks!

Comment: Curious.

So I'm pretty sure the reason it's not working is because select() isnt waiting for the sockets to time out before retrieving their status (given the error code they return is 10061) causing an all around failure rate. Would an appropriate way to solve this issue be to store each socket in some sort of vector/array, connect() them all, and then run select() on each one after they are given a second to attempt to connect & time out?

or would it be more appropriate to set the timeout value shorter somehow?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `connect(2)`, the OS initiates the [three-way handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment) by sending a `SYN` packet to the other peer.  If no response is received, it waits a little bit and sends a few more `SYN` packets.  If no response is still received after a given timeout, then the operation fails, and `connect(2)` returns with the error code `ETIMEODOUT`.

Ordinarily, if a peer is up but not accepting TCP connections on a given port, it will reply to any `SYN` packets with a `RST` packet.  This will cause `connect(2)` to fail much more quickly (one network round-trip time) with the error `ECONNREFUSED`.  However, if the peer has a firewall set up, it'll just ignore your `SYN` packets and won't send those `RST` packets, which will cause `connect(2)` to take a long time to fail.

So, if you want to avoid waiting for that timeout for every port, you need to do multiple connections in parallel.  You can do this multithreading (one synchronous `connect(2)` call per thread), but this doesn't scale well since threads take up a fair amount of resources.

The better method would be to use non-blocking sockets.  To make a socket non-blocking, call [`fcntl(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) with the `F_SETFL` option and the `O_NONBLOCK` option.  Then, `connect(2)` will return immediately with either `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN`, at which point you can use either [`select(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or [`poll(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) and friends to monitor a large number of sockets at once.

Comment: my compiler throws me an error when i pass F_SETFL and O_NONBLOCK to fcntl(), saying that theyre not being declared. I cant seem to find any documentation or examples that have the need of anyone declaring them either...

All examples i found online just pass them in as is. fcntl itself doesnt have any compile issues

Comment: @user1324674: Make sure you `#include <fcntl.h>`.  Also, to ensure you don't unset any flags which were set before, you need to also do an `F_GETFL`.  So to set `O_NONBLOCK`, you'd do `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);` (but don't forget to add error checking).

Comment: I guess i failed to mention that I am using windows for this project.

Apparently fcntl does not work here

Comment: @user1324674: In that case, then you should instead use the [`ioctlsocket()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the `FIONBIO` command to make the socket non-blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an array of non-blocking sockets to queue up a bunch of connection attempts at once.

Read about it [here](http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial/winsock/winsock_tutorial_3.shtm)

Comment: Oops, seems I'm too late as this has already been suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution that works on windows. First I added:

```
u_long on = 1;
timeval tv = {0, 1000};      //timeout value in microseconds
fd_set fds;
FD_ZERO(&fds);
```

then i changed this code to look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < a_size(port_no); i++)
{
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    FD_SET(sock, &fds);

    ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &on);

    target.sin_family = AF_INET;
    target.sin_port = htons(port_no[i]);
    target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);

    connect(sock, (SOCKADDR *)&target, sizeof(target));
    err = select(sock, &fds, &fds, &fds, &tv);

    if (err != SOCKET_ERROR && err != 0)
        cout << "Port: " << port_no[i] << " - open" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Port: " << port_no[i] << " - closed" << endl;
    closesocket(sock);
}
```

and it seems to function much faster now! I will do some work to optimize it & clean it up a bit, but thank you for all your input everyone who responded! :)